# Javascript beginner failure

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am currently working on a task for a class which i need to build arrays of arrays to produce a program that allows a user to input his/her name and date of birth. my code is the following,

```
// global array
var globalNameArray = [];

//setting up variablrd

//DOB Conversion

var getAge = function (dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    };
    return age;
};
var initialize = function () {
    "use strict";
// list of all objects being used in functions
    var paraRef, name, DOB, sum, mean, count,age, meanRef, sumRef, countRef, nameAndDOB, tempArray = [], i;
    //connecting the elements to the html page
    paraRef = document.getElementById('displayNumbers');
    name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    DOB = document.getElementById('DOB').value;
    meanRef = document.getElementById('mean');
    sumRef = document.getElementById('sum');
    countRef = document.getElementById('count');

    age = getAge(DOB);
    //arrays - name and DOB Array
    nameAndDOB = [];
// array with what information going into it
    nameAndDOB = [ name, DOB];
// pushing the names array into the global array
    globalNameArray.push(nameAndDOB);
    count = globalNameArray.length;
    countRef.innerHTML = count;
// for loop for temp array getting the inputs and adding it to the global
    /*sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
        tempArray = [];
        tempArray = globalNameArray[i];
        sum += (tempArray[1]);
    }*/
    paraRef.innerHTML += name;
    paraRef.innerHTML += "  ";
    paraRef.innerHTML += DOB;
    paraRef.innerHTML += "<br>";

    //showing the values
    sumRef.innerHTML = sum;
    meanRef.innerHTML = mean;
};
```

i cant seem to display the converted age of the users nor the mean and sum of all ages, anyone know what i can do?

Comment: The beginner failure is to NOT use jQuery... Let's do it easier.

I also advise you to use the console.log(text) function to sea what's happening.

Comment: can you show your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your problem is with the calculation or insert values in your HTML, but your loop is a good start:

```
nameAndDOB = {"name":name, "DOB": DOB}; // i use an object but an array is fine too.

globalNameArray.push(nameAndDOB);

var sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {    
    sum += getAge(globalNameArray[i].DOB);
}

var mean = (sum / count).toFixed(2);

//showing the values
sumRef.innerHTML = sum;
meanRef.innerHTML = mean;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the brief, write a program to enter a series of names and associated birth dates (yyy-mm-dd) and put them into an array of arrays. The names, birth dates and ages can then be displayed one per line, followed by the count, total age, and mean age.

The user enters a name and associated DoB one at a time.
The names and birth dates are stored in an array of arrays.
A list of all the names, birth dates and ages can be displayed, one per line, followed by the count, sum of the ages, and mean age.
Note: the alert command is not to be used to display the data and the prompt command is not to be used to enter data. 
 {html code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> PSP01</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="psp1.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>PSP01 Assignment</h2>
<p>
Enter a name and a DOB to add to the array
</p>

<form  action="#">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td style = "text-align:right;">Name:</td>
<td>
   <input id ="name" type="text" />
</td>
<td rowspan="2">
   <input type="button" id="submit"  value="submit" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style = "text-align:right;">DOB:</td>
<td>
   <input id="DOB" type="date" />
</td>
</tr>

<br />
<br>

</br>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td style = "text-align:right;">Age:</td>
<td id="Age" style="width:100px">&#160;</td>
<td style = "text-align:right;">count:</td>
<td id="count" style="width:100px">&#160;</td>
<td style = "text-align:right;">Sum:</td>
<td id="sum" style="width:100px">&#160;</td>
<td style="text-align:right;">Mean:</td>
<td id="mean" style="width:100px">&#160;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<p id="displayNumbers"> </p> 
<script>
//add an event listener to the submit button
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener('click', initialize, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```